# How to make both text and image change on rollover via CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, css-sprites

I have a top menu that has an icon - and underneath it there's text for the icon.

```
----------      -----------
|        |      |         |
|  icon  |      |    ?    |
----------      -----------
   Text          Questions

<li class="questions">
    <a href="/questions" id="questions">
    <i class="questions_icon"></i>
    Questions
    </a>
</li>
```

Using a sprite I have the icon change on :hover.
I also have the text change in color on :hover.

However, I would l like to know if it's possible to:

- change the icon when the text is hovered -- and
- change the text when the icon is hovered.

Is this possible using CSS alone?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to add a bit more html to toggle between multiple spans on hover. You'll want to premeditate the text, and make on span visible, and the other invisible. Changing those attributes when hovering using css.

Comment: I might be behind the times here but what is <i>?

Comment: <i> is just markup used as placeholder for a background image -- used to be _italic_ -- this is frequently used on Twitter and FB (the placeholder)

Comment: So what are you changing the text to?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding understanding the situation? Why don't you just set a hover on the `li` `.questions` to target the text and the icon? I.e when `.questions` is hovered (which contains both the icon and the text) both would change.

Comment: li.questions a  { color: pink}
li.questions:hover a {color: red}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like this:

```
.questions:hover i {
    background-image: url(...);
}
.questions:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO (no images): http://jsfiddle.net/kFkcV/

```
.container::after {
  content: "Hello World";
}

.container::before {
  content: /images/icon1.png;
}

.container:hover:after {
  content: "Hover World!";
}

.container:hover:before {
  content: /images/icon2.png;
}
```

​

Comment: The `content` property, yuck!

Comment: so what's up with `content`... haven't ever used it and wonder if will run OK on IE7-8... any downsides?